# Does table sorter work without CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have a folder 'test' in the root of my hosting. I downloaded a sorter plugin from http://tablesorter.com and uploaded 'jquery' folder in the 'test' folder i created. Then I made an html table in the index.html file in the 'test' folder.

I entered the below within the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

Then I entered the following script within the head tag

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter();
        } 
    ); 
</script>
```

In the table I entered

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border="1" width="100%">
```

Still the sorter is not working... As far as I know, I followed proper instructions. What did i do something wrong?

MY path is public_html/mydomain.com/test
The the files under test folder is

1. jquery
2. index.html

The files under jquery folder is

1. jquery-latest.js
2. jquery.metadata.js
3. jquery.tablesorter.js
4. jquery.tablesorter.min.js

After playing with the code for a while i found the problem. I downloaded a bootstrap template and added a table to it and at the bottom, just before /body tag there are 3 paths

```
<script src="./js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="./js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>
```

If I remove this, the sorter works but then the website stops working. Any ideas???

Comment: exactly what you described works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/afgpz039/1/)
(copied from tablesorder.com demos), check if you have correct paths when including jquery and tablesorter plugin

Comment: even i am confused and it is driving me crazy. i checked the paths and as far as i can see its all correct. I have updated my original question with the paths. The only additional thing what I did was I added my css style. Please help me.

Comment: i found the problem and edited my question. still no solution :(

Comment: @paulitto thanks... I have understood the entire tablesorter script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of juggling with the paths and I did not understand the logic but it worked.

This is what I did

I kept the following in head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

I kept one more instance of the following in before /body end tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

and placed both the files in both the folders /jquery and the default /js folder included in the website template

Phew!

Comment: I think you might have a javascript error. I remember that the original tablesorter uses `$.browser` which was [removed in jQuery v1.9](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/). So either use an older version of jQuery, or switch to my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)